# Python Floating Point Formatting

Tags: python, floating-point, format

I've seen a few questions about this already, but none that I read helped me actually understand why what I am trying to do is failing.

So I have a bunch of floating point values, and they have different precisions. Some are 0.1 others are 1.759374, etc. And I want to format them so they are ALL in the form of "+0.0000000E+00" I tried doing

```
number = '%1.7f' % oldnumber
```

but that didn't work. I thought what I was telling it to do was "one digit perfor the decimal point, and 7 after, float" but it doesn't work. I'm not really getting the examples in the docs, which don't seem to even bother with "before and after decimal point" issues, and I didn't find a question that was about before and after decimal point fixing.

Now, I know that some of my numbers are 0.0437 or similar, and I want them to appear as 4.3700000E-02 or something. I was sort of hoping it would do the E bit on it's own, but if it doesn't how do I do it?

Here is the exact line I have:

```
RealValConv =   '%1.7g' % struct.unpack('!f',    RealVal.decode('hex'))[0]
```

RealVal is a hex number that represents the value I want.

Also, this is in Python 2.7

Comment: You want to use `g` rather than `f` if you want scientific notation. For instance, `"%1.7g" % .0000012323` becomes `'1.2323e-06'`. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why, but that isn't working. I'm using python 2.7, does that matter? That is the behavior I wanted though.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: `%g` uses `%f` in some cases, e.g., formatting `math.pi` with `%1.7g` results in `3.141593`.  `%e` always uses "e" notation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> '{:.7e}'.format(0.00000000000000365913456789)
'3.6591346e-15'
```

Comment: My problems with length were an excel problem, not a program problem. (I open the file as .csv and excel defaulted it to being shorter)

Comment: Always, **always**, prefer `.format` over `%` formatting.  Here is yet another reason it is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the scientific notation format: Something like this:

```
number = '%e' % oldnumber

>>> x = 1.759374
>>> print '%e' % x
1.759374e+00
>>>
>>> x = 1.79
>>> print '%e' % x
1.790000e+00
>>>
>>> x = 1.798775655
>>> print '%e' % x
1.798776e+00
>>>
```

Or, if you want to control precision, you can use the format method as sugged by @leon approach (+1).

```
>>> x = 1.759374
>>>
>>> print('{:.2e}'.format(x))
1.76e+00
>>>
>>> print('{:.10e}'.format(x))
1.7593740000e+00
>>>
>>> print('{:.4e}'.format(x))
1.7594e+00
>>>
```

Comment: I actually get a default precision of 7 decimal values. If you want to control, then you can use format() method as suggested by @leon. I have updated my answer, accordingly.

Comment: My problems with length were an excel problem, not a program problem. (I open the file as .csv and excel defaulted it to being shorter) Sorry for assuming it was you, when it was me. Dizzy days.

Comment: Thnx for telling me that. Appreciate that!