# Why there is weird scientific notation in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Whenever I print the array inside a loop it displays it as

```
[  1.170e-01   2.187e+08   2.000e-02]
```

Even though I used the following code

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True,precision=3)
```

After the code is run I copy paste the same output as

```
a1=[  1.170e-01,   2.187e+08 ,  2.000e-02]
print a1
```

And it prints it correctly as

```
[0.117, 218700000.0, 0.02]
```

Obviously this is bad behaviour in NumPy? Printing inside a loop and outside a loop shouldn't matter!

The actual code is

```
ll = (calib_params+np.sqrt(np.diag(params[1])*residuals/(len(data_outsample)-3))*nstd)
ul = (calib_params-np.sqrt(np.diag(params[1])*residuals/(len(data_outsample)-3))*nstd)
print ll
print ul
```

I even tried `np.round(ll,3)` and `np.round(ul,3)` but sadly none of them work.

Can't suppress scientific display!

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to numpy, but to Python floating point representation as a string generally. You have come across two different default behaviors (scientific notation and plain decimal).

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) describes formatting floating points as strings.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709000/python-floating-point-formatting) is a Stack Overflow entry on the topic.

The following code formats a number to three decimals:

```
print('%1.3f'% .333333333333333333333333)
```

Output

```
0.333
```